# Why does my Ubuntu machine not have the /dev/cpu/0/cpuid directoy?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I try to run `./TurionPowerControl -spec` as obtained from the following link (note that it had to be slightly modified to be compatible with a newer GCC):
https://github.com/turionpowercontrol/tpc/wiki

I get the following output:

```
Turion Power States Optimization and Control - by blackshard

ERROR: couldn't open /dev/cpu/0/cpuid (No such file or directory). Make sure that cpuid module is loaded.
```

My question is simply: Why is there no such file or directory in my system? I am using Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS on a Dell Inspiron 1501 Laptop. I looked through the code and I found the following snippet in sysdep-linux.cpp, which I think contains the line of code that outputs the error message:

```
#include <term.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <signal.h>

#include "cpuPrimitives.h"

bool initializeCore()
{
        int fd;

        fd = open("/dev/cpu/0/cpuid", O_RDONLY);
        if (fd == -1) {
                printf("ERROR: couldn't open /dev/cpu/0/cpuid (%s).", strerror(errno));
                if (errno == ENXIO || errno == ENOENT) {
                        printf(" Make sure that cpuid module is loaded.\n");
                        return false;
                }
                if (errno == EACCES) {
                        printf(" Not root?.\n");
                        return false;
                }
                printf("\n");
                return false;
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because, as illustrated in [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LongRunHowTo), it uses the CPUID device driver, which is not installed by default:

```
sudo apt-get install -y cpuid
```

See the [driver description here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man4/cpuid.4.html).

The [OP Nicholas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4505322/nicholas) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244943/why-does-my-ubuntu-machine-not-have-the-dev-cpu-0-cpuid-directoy/60244978#comment106563874_60244978) having to add a modules ([modprob](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/modprobe.htm))

```
sudo modprobe cpuid
```

Comment: Had to use the command "sudo modprobe cpuid"! Thank you for guiding me in the right direction.